# Does South Korea have trains from Andong to Jeonju?

Tags: trains, south-korea

A rail map showed a line from Andong (안동) to Jeonju (전주).  But Google Maps says I have to go transfer twice on a much longer route.  Korail schedule search says there are no direct trains and transfer routes are not possible.  I presume the difference in wording between the two is significant but I don't know what it means.

Bus is more direct and faster (four+ hours vs. six+), but I already have a flexible four-day Korail pass paid for (with one day already used).

Comment: What map are you looking at? Everything I just googled shows maps with no direct connection

Comment: I would have to go find it again.  I re-used the browser tab.

Comment: oops, I just looked at the approximate location and not the name.  So it goes _near_ to Jeonju (daejon—대존)  And I didn't say it showed a direct route, but it does show a route much closer to a straight line than the one Google offered.  But (probably) three transfers where Google only showed two.  But Korail won't show any route. at all.

Comment: When I search the Korail schedule it doesn't say the route is not possible, it says I need to call to make a reservation. Perhaps two or three transfers and a mix of high-speed and conventional service (as a look at the [rail lines map](http://info.korail.com/mbs/english/subview.jsp?id=english_050402000000) suggests is required) makes it too complex an itinerary, or too long, to be booked via the website.

Comment: Are you sure it's a passenger line and not a freight line?

Comment: It's not quite as direct as I thought, but if it exists, it's better than what Google says is the best.  And no, I'm not sure.  But I think if the map were showing freight routes, it would show a lot more than it did.

Answer (score 2):

You'll be much better off trying with buses. The train system has been designed to connect Seoul and the provinces, not so much the provinces together. You'd probably have to go back to Seoul, and go down again to Jeonju. Daejeon (대전) is nowhere near Jeonju btw.

Comment: As I said, I already have a paid TRAIN pass.  Daejeon is only an hour by bus.  That seems pretty close to me.  But my mistake was that the map didn't show Jeonju and Daejeon was visually in the right area on the map.  According to Google, it's not necessary to go all the way back to Seoul.  There is another route that goes thirty or forty percent back to Seoul and then transfer to a train headed southwest.  But it leaves Andong around two AM.